# How can I remove this expression?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I recently used this tool so I am bigger.
when I wrote codes, suddenly this expression appeared.
How can I remove this expression?
thank you.

[image]

Comment: it has nothing to do with Spring.  It is related the IDE (which is Spring-STS, which is based on Eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

It notice you that is a tab space:

You can change the configuration like this :

**Window** -> **Preferences** -> **General** -> **Text** **Editor**.

Then uncheck **Show white spaces character**

[image]